# My SSD Drive has two partitons System at 125gb and C using the rest. Is 125 too large?

Tags: windows, system-reserved-partition

My SSD drive (added after windows 10) has two partitions. One is the System partition of 125gb Healthy (system, Active, primary partition) and a second "Windows" C Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition).

It seems like the first partition of 125gb is rather large. I have read that this partition is expected to be less than a gb.

Is 125gb too large and if so how can I correct.

Comment: Please take the time to edit your question's title.  You should also spend time to clarify what your question is.

Comment: Is that really 125GB (gigabytes) or is it rather MB (megabytes)?

Comment: It is 125 gig.... which is about a third of my SSD drive. I would love to shrink this to a gig or two....

Answer (score 0):

Using MBR style partition scheme the active partition is also the "System partition" - the System partition is where boot related files are expected to be.

There is no problem for System partition being 125GB.

You could even make your current C: partition active (and System), write boot files on C: and delete the 125 GB partition.

Use "bootsect.exe" to write boot sectors and MBR.

Use "bcdboot.exe" to re/create boot related files on any partition (but they have meaning only on active partition!)

You could also optimize System partition (move files to begin of partition and then shrink it to say 500MB if you like. Usually Windows reserves 100MB for the System partition when installing to unformatted disk, and creates a separate recovery partition.

See Microsoft recommendations about "[Configure BIOS/MBR-Based Hard Drive Partitions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825146.aspx)"

Also "[BIOS/MBR-based hard drive partitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions)"

Comment: Thanks very much for the info, I will look into how to shrink the system partition to a few gig, and also see if I can understand any consequences of that action. about a third of my SSD is now system and it would be nice to free up some of that space.